# Medium range rfid

Tags: rfid

I need to design/build a system that can detect a stationary line-side device    as a ride-on miniature railway train passes by.  The line-side device will transmit to the train the prevailing speed limit for the track section ahead.
My difficulty is in finding a low cost device that will work at a distance of say 0.5m.  I can only find modules that work at very small distances (tag readers) or very expensive modules that work at much higher (not needed) distances.  Is there anything *inexpensive* that works at the intermediate range of around half a meter?

Comment: I think you will find the read speed of even the expensive RFID readers would not be fast enough for this task.  Is this a school / collage project or real life?  If real life is a Pi and your coding fail-safe enough for the risk?